# JPA findBy multiple items optionally

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm looking for a simple solution to an ugly problem. I am using Spring Data JPA and have 7 entities that are all related. I have a need to do a findByEntity1_NameAndEntity2_NameAndEntity3_NameAndEntity4_NameAndEntity5_NameAndEntity6_NameAndEntity7_Name

I need every permutation including and excluding each other those entities. I could build all 128 methods and use a big case statement to select which one to use, but that's horridly ugly. I feel like I'm missing the easy button on this one.

Comment: Would it be easier to implement with a native query?

Answer (score 0):

**Query By Example method**

I think the best option for you is to use the (imo, somewhat infrequently used) `QueryByExample` feature of Spring Data JPA. On researching this answer, [I posted an answer somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780226/spring-data-ignore-parameter-if-it-has-a-null-value/54103282#54103282) that needed the same response. I'd take a look at that to get an idea of how this solves your problem.

You'll first need to the `QueryByExampleExecutor` to your `Repository`. 
Secondly you'll just need to create your query like so (and hopefully you're using [fluent builders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818287/should-i-use-builder-pattern-in-dto) for your entities!):

```
ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnoreNullValues();
Example<MyObject> exampleQuery = Example.of(new MyObject()
    .withEntity1(new Entity1().withName("foo"), matcher);
repository.findAll(exampleQuery);
```

Would select all of the `MyObject` elements with `Entity1` having `name` of `foo`.

```
ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().withIgnoreNullValues();
Example<MyObject> exampleQuery = Example.of(new MyObject()
    .withEntity1(new Entity1().withName("foo"),
    .withEntity2(new Entity2().withName("bar"),
    .withEntity3(new Entity3().withName("baz"),
    .withEntity4(new Entity4().withName("foo"),
    .withEntity5(new Entity5().withName("bar"),
    .withEntity6(new Entity6().withName("baz"),
    .withEntity7(new Entity7().withName("foo")
), matcher);
repository.findAll(exampleQuery);
```

Would select all of the `MyObject` elements for `Entity1` with `name` of `foo`, `Entity2`, with `name` of `bar`, etc.